# Display Flatlist Array for React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to display the flat list arrays of cluster1 only with a,b,c,d,e without affecting cluster 2. I want to show the flat list of only cluster 1 but I have no idea how.

This is my data

```
    const Cluster = [
    {cluster1: [
      {
        name: 'a'
      },
      {
        name: 'b'
      },
      {
        name: 'c'
      },
      {
        name: 'd'
      },
      {
        name: 'e'
      },
    ]
  },

  {cluster2: [
    {
      name: 'h'
    },
    {
      name: 'i'
    },
    {
      name: 'j'
    },
    {
      name: 'k'
    },
    {
      name: 'l'
    }
  ]
}   
]
module.exports = { Cluster: Cluster };
```

This is my flat list code

```
class Flatlist extends Component{
render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return(
        <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
        numColumns= {2}
        data={Cluster}
        renderItem={({item,index})=>{
            return(
                <FlatListItem item={item} index={index}>

                </FlatListItem>);
        }}
        >
        </FlatList>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

FlatlistItem

```
class FlatListItem extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.list}>
        <View>


        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>

        </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Basically, I want to display the alphabets in the array of cluster 1. I hope someone is able to help me with this issue

Comment: Does this work to display both lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is more of filtering the array to find a specific object. So here's my approach- First find the required cluster in your `Cluster` array. I am assuming that it exists. Necessary error handling can be done.

```
const getClusterByName = (name) => 
    Cluster.find(cluster => cluster.hasOwnProperty(name))[name]
```

Then simply pass it to the `FlatList`

```
<FlatList
    data={getClusterByName('cluster1')}
    ...
/>
```